# Angular add function reply comments

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code which adds new comments, but the "reply to comment" feature isn't working properly. If I push form add comment when click `reply()` and add then inside/under existing comment only five times.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="comments-app" ng-app="addCommentsApp" ng-controller="AddCommentsController as commCtrl">

  <div class="comments">

    <div class="comment" hide-me="5000" ng-repeat="comment in commCtrl.comments | orderBy: 'date'">

      <div class="comment-box">
        <div class="comment-footer">
          <div class="comment-info">
            <span class="comment-date">{{ comment.date | date: 'medium' }}</span>
          </div>

          <div class="comment-actions">
            <a ng-click="reply()">Reply</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-text">{{ comment.text }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- From -->
  <div class="comment-form">

    <form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && commCtrl.addComment()" novalidate>
      <div class="form-row">
        <textarea
                  class="input"
                  ng-model="commCtrl.comment.text"
                  placeholder="Add comment..."
                  required></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

 var myApp = angular.module('addCommentsApp', []);
    myApp.controller('AddCommentsController', AddCommentsController);

  // Inject $scope dependency.
  AddCommentsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];

  // Declare AddCommentsController.
  function AddCommentsController($scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    // Current comment.
    vm.comment = {};

    // Array where comments will be.
    vm.comments = [];

    // Fires when form is submited.
    vm.addComment = function() {

      // Add current date to the comment.
      vm.comment.date = Date.now();

      vm.comments.push( vm.comment );
      vm.comment = {};

      // Reset clases of the form after submit.
      $scope.form.$setPristine();
    }
  }

})();
```

CSS:

```
.comment-form .form .input{
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  color: #555f77;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.comment-form .form textarea.input{
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.comment-form .form input[type=submit]{
  background-color: #555f77;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding: 6px 15px;
}

.comment-form .form .input.disabled {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.comment-form,
.comment{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.comment .comment-box{
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  margin-left: 100px;
  min-height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}

.comment .comment-box:before,
.comment .comment-box:after{
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #FCFCFC;
  content: "";
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}

.comment .comment-box:before{
  border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
   top: 22px;
}

.comment .comment-footer:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.comment .comment-footer a{
  color: #acb4c2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.comment .comment-footer a:hover{
  color: #555f77;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.comment .comment-info{
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
}

.comment .comment-date:before{
  content: "|";
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.comment-actions{
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 15%;
}
```

There is also a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/kurzalowski/eefyap1y/

Comment: I have copied your code from your fiddle into your question. (We shouldn't have to visit external resources to understand what you're asking. Unfortunately, I don't understand what you mean by "If I push form add comment when click reply() and add then inside/under existing comment." Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `addComment` to:

```
vm.addComment = function(oldComment) {
  if (oldComment !== undefined) {

    oldComment.comment.date = Date.now();

    if (!oldComment.comments) {
      oldComment.comments = [];
    }

    oldComment.comments.push({
      text: oldComment.comment.text,
      date: oldComment.comment.date
    });        
  } else {
    // Add current date to the comment.
    vm.comment.date = Date.now();
    vm.comments.push(vm.comment);
    vm.comment = {};        
  }
// Reset clases of the form after submit.
    $scope.form.$setPristine();
```

So structure will be:

```
[
  {
    "text": "sdsd",
    "date": 1504440173932,
    "showReply": true,
    "comment": {
      "text": "aaaaa2",
      "date": 1504440258984
    },
    "comments": [
      {
        "text": "aaaaa",
        "date": 1504440176459
      },
      {
        "text": "aaaaa2",
        "date": 1504440258984
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czcgfa8m/)</kbd>

---

*Full HTML*

```
<div class="comments-app" ng-app="addCommentsApp" ng-controller="AddCommentsController as commCtrl">

  <div class="comments">

    <div class="comment" hide-me="5000" ng-repeat="comment in commCtrl.comments | orderBy: 'date'">

      <div class="comment-box">
        <div class="comment-footer">
          <div class="comment-info">
            <span class="comment-date">{{ comment.date | date: 'medium' }}</span>
          </div>

          <div class="comment-actions">
            <a href="" ng-click="commCtrl.reply(comment)">Reply</a>

            <div ng-if="comment.showReply">
              <div class="comment" hide-me="5000" ng-repeat="subcomment in comment.comments | orderBy: 'date'">

                <p>{{subcomment.text}}</p>

              </div>

              <form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && commCtrl.addComment(comment)" novalidate>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <textarea class="input" ng-model="comment.comment.text" placeholder="Add comment..." required></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <input type="submit" value="SEND">
                </div>
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="comment-text">{{ comment.text }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- From -->
    <div class="comment-form">

      <form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && commCtrl.addComment()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-row">
          <textarea class="input" ng-model="commCtrl.comment.text" placeholder="Add comment..." required></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="submit" value="SEND">
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>   
  </div>
```

Comment: @kurzalowski well, I think Demo I posted does most of stuff you asked. You will be able to sort things out like fix date - as home work :)  Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have only one question yet - when do reply how to hidden/remove text area, button... after send reply ?
And make reply again - now I can reply only once

Comment: @kurzalowski add `oldComment.comment.text = '';` https://jsfiddle.net/czcgfa8m/  Also you welcome to accept

Comment: oldComment.comment.text = ''; only clear input
but how set comment.showReply = false;

Comment: @kurzalowski    mate, In Stack Overflow we post answers that give you directions how to solve issues and help you to move forward. In this case you wait when someone will give you full code. here is a link and im sure you can achieve it alone :) https://jsfiddle.net/3qnsww60/

Answer (score 0):

As i have checked your code you did not define **reply()** function in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can add repliedComments array to your comment object as -

```
vm.comment = {};
vm.comment.repliedComments=[]; /// here you can maintain the replied comments of your object.
```

Its better to maintain your comments by some unique Ids so that you can maintain the replied comments easily.